# Populating and updating a ListView in Xamarin

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, populate

I just want to populate a ListView in Xamarin with data and update it, so that the items get visible. Now I searched a lot and tried this:

```
    List<string> items = new List<string> ();
    ArrayAdapter ListAdapter = null;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
        ListView listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);

        ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);
        listView.Adapter = ListAdapter;

        button.Click += delegate { Server(listView); };
    }
```

Now the method 'Server' has following code:

```
 items.Add("The server is running at port localEndPoint...");                
 ListAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```

This does absolutely nothing. Nothing gets updated. I also tried:

```
 RunOnUiThread(() =>
 {
   ListAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
 });
```

but here it does not even jump into the RunOnUiThread.

What am I doing wrong? I'm very new to Xamarin.

UPDATE: Full Server Code:

```
  try
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

            /* Initializes the Listener */
            TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 8001);

            /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */
            myList.Start();

            ListAdapter.Add("The server is running at port localEndPoint...");
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                ListAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            });

            Console.WriteLine("The local End point is  :" +
                              myList.LocalEndpoint);
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");

            Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

            byte[] b = new byte[100];
            int k = s.Receive(b);
            Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));

            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server."));
            Console.WriteLine("\nSent Acknowledgement");
            /* clean up */
            s.Close();
            myList.Stop();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
        }
```

Comment: I suppose your listView is null. Verify that you FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1); does return a non null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the item to the ArrayAdapter itself:

```
 ListAdapter.Add("The server is running at port localEndPoint...");        
 ListAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```

If your code runs on background thread you will need to wrap it in `RunOnUiThread` as you have mentioned in your question.

Comment: @Canox: Does the code in `Server` run on background thead?

Comment: Like above it's going through a delegate. I'm calling TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 8001); and myList.Start(); - Could this be blocking the ListView?

Comment: @Canox: Can you try updating listview before starting the listener?

Comment: I put it in an own method. It works now. When I put it before starting the listener it does not work. How can this be avoided?

Comment: @Canox: Post the full code of Server method in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110355/discussion-between-giorgi-and-canox).